MSBuild outputting all files in uppercase
We are using Azure Devops to build our .NET projects and making use of the Visual Studio build task. Our build server has decided to start outputting all files in uppercase. This is causing subsequent failures in our build and release pipelines.
I can replicate this behaviour on our build server using the following command:
MSBuild.exe OurSolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"

Every file output to the \bin folder is in UPPERCASE. There is nothing suspicious in the .csproj files, and this is happening across all solutions and projects which did not have this issue a few days ago.
As a note I have tried updating the Azure Devops build agent, and the Visual Studio 2022 build tools that are installed on the server.
Edit:
The MSBuild log shows the correct casing in the output files. The \obj folder also contains files with the correct casing. As such it appears the uppercase renaming is occurring when the files are copied from the \obj to the \bin folder

Try msbuild.exe OurSolution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /verbosity:diagnostic to get a full output of what msbuild is doing there (if the issue might be msbuild or some target-file)

I've tried with a brand new Console App to make the log manageable. MSBuild shows the output files in the correct casing, however the output is still being renamed to be uppercase. Interestingly the file properties show the original filename in the correct casing.

If the MSBuild log shows the correct casing, it's probably not MSBuild.

Agreed, but I’m at a loss as to what else could be causing it

Could you please try to run the same code on the Microsoft hosted agent to check if the issue is still there? This can help narrow down the issue. Also, you can check if your VS has set a property function to make the output file to upper case.  Please refer this question.

The issue doesn't occur on the Microsoft hosted agent, nor my machine, so it does appear specific to this build server. I can't see any property functions but I've also now tried removing all VS build tools and re-installed Visual Studio on the server - it's fine if I build through VS but the issue persists if I use MSBuild directly ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe")

It seems there is some issue in your server. If possible, you can try to reconfigure the server. By the way, you can also try the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task instead of the Visual Studio build task to see if it can be a workaround of the issue.

Hi @RobKite, may I know if you have found the cause of the issue?

Unfortunately not yet. The DotNetCoreCLI@2 task is a workaround for the building of the solution, however I was still finding that our NuGet packages (build as part of that task) are being changed to uppercase when copied to the artifact staging directory before they are pushed to our NuGet server (the release process currently fails as the search for .nupkg files is case sensitive).
We are in the process of setting up an alternative build agent machine as it does appear machine specific but we have had no success in trying to resolve directly.

Thanks for your update.  It sounds like the problem occurs when copying files to another folder. Since the cause of the problem has not yet been found, and the problem only occurs in this build server, reconfiguring a new build server is indeed the best choice.

According to the troubleshooting you did, we can summary that it seems the issue occur when copying files to another folder. And the issue is not related to Azure DevOps.
The DotNetCoreCLI@2 task serves as a workaround for building the solution, but there are still issues with NuGet packages being changed to uppercase when copied to the artifact staging directory.
Since the problem only occurs on this build server, reconfiguring a new build server is indeed the best choice.

unfortunately in this case the only solution we could find was indeed to reconfigure a new server, here's to hoping it doesn't occur again!
